# telnet timing out from aws ec2 to sendgrid

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, sendgrid, telnet

I am trying to configure [listmonk](https://listmonk.app/) with AWS EC2 and sendgrid. However I'm getting timeout while sending mails. I tried debugging using the [documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/smtp-connectivity-timeout-issues-ses/) and when I try to telnet, I'm getting timeout:

```sh
# Command
telnet smtp.sendgrid.net 25
```

[image]

I checked the outbound settings and everything is whitlisted:

[image]

Is there anything else I need to do to telnet to smtp.sendgrid.net?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, [AWS blocks outbound traffic on port 25](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-port-25-throttle/), and you have to file a request to get the restriction removed.

I usually just use a different SMTP port instead of trying to get port 25 opened. [SendGrid's documentation states](https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/sending-email/getting-started-smtp):

> SendGrid accepts unencrypted and TLS connections on ports 25, 587, &
> 2525. You can also connect via SSL on port 465. Many hosting providers and ISPs block port 25 as a default practice. If your Telent session
> continually times out or will not connect using port 25, it is likely
> that your ISP or hosting provider is blocking the port. You can
> contact your host/ISP to find out which ports are open for outgoing
> SMTP relay. We recommend using port 587 to avoid any rate limiting
> that your server host may apply.

I suggest just switching to use port `587`

Comment: thank you, that just solved my problem

Comment: i spent whole week debugging my application due to this issue :(